# Owl Carousel not showing images

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm trying to add a photo carousel to my project, but Owl carousel won't show my images (src is definitely correct), it shows the whole container with the nav dots at the bottom and prev/next buttons, but not my images.

Would appreciate any help!

html:

```
 <head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="plugins/owl-carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img  src="images/1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img  src="images/9.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img  src="images/10.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <img  src="images/11.jpg">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins//owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        autoPlay: 1000,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:5
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: is there a live preview?

Answer (score 10):

I have figured out my issue.
Apparently Owl Carousel has a problem with pages set to rtl.

In order to fix my issue, all I had to do is add `rtl:true` to the jquery function.

Thanks to all the helpers!

Answer (score 1):

can you please try below code

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        autoPlay: 1000,
         items:10,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:10
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" media="screen"> 

<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
     <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
  <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img  src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to use jquery 1.12.4 for a certein plugin. this code works, though the buttons don't, they just sit there statically. Is it because of my jquery version?

Comment: wait i will provide example with using your query

Comment: @Dor GOlan i have add updated changes with your code can you please check and let me know if any query

Comment: I've tried your code, now the container isn't showing at all

Comment: you need only single image slider ?

Comment: No, I need the slider for around 8-10 images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170606/discussion-between-ppl-and-dor-golan).

Answer (score 0):

you used double / in script path
change it with this

```
<script src="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was so hoping that was the issue, but sadly it isn't. Result is still the same.

Comment: Also try to remove extra space before "src" attribute

Comment: and remove "owl-item" class

Answer (score 0):

Please just change class `owl-item` to other own name except owl carousel default keyword because it will conflict. **[see](https://jsfiddle.net/cdg04fkm/1/)**

Comment: I tried creating a new class for the items as you showed, still not change.

Comment: Here is working fiddle so i need see live because i have create from your markup.

Comment: Just change this class name http://prntscr.com/jf7iy5

And check image path also

https://jsfiddle.net/cdg04fkm/2/

i have use older jQuery version as you used also